# How could I stop IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio from downloading android source?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

It really takes too much time to download android-source.

I do not need to check for the source code while developing, and I've successfully build the project under command line using gradle.

But when I tried to use IntelliJ IDEA to open it, it starts downloading the source of android and never ends, every single time. It just stop me from developing.

Comment: what source do you mean?

Comment: @pskink like `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.1.2-3/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.1.2-3-source.jar`

Comment: I'll show you a screenshot, wait

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, sorry, kotlin? what kotlin? are you using android studio 3 alpha?

Comment: ![20170519174135](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16398479/26242384/ddae8968-3c4d-11e7-9bb9-3060ecbdac90.png)
here

Comment: @pskink any idea?

Comment: what are you doing in kotlin? are you using it at all?

Comment: It's not the problem of Kotlin. The problem is, the IDE download source jar of every dependencies in my project. Kotlin's source code is just a part of it.

Comment: Do you have `downloadSources = true` anywhere in your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: thats not the the default behaviour. check if your run your build with ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies. Is it possible that your dependencies folder gets cleared or you hdd is full somehow?

Comment: No, @FierceFox it works fine with command line. I used `gradle assembleRelease` and it successfully generates the apk, but when I open the project with IDE, it starts downloading the source.

Comment: No, @CrazyCoder it works fine with command line. I used gradle assembleRelease and it successfully generates the apk, but when I open the project with IDE, it starts downloading the source.

Comment: It's not necessary to solve this now. The stupid IntelliJ IDEA has already download all the sources.